# Bluetooth Android to Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, sockets, bluetooth, uuid

I am trying to make an application that transfers Strings of data from my Android phone to my Laptop running Windows 7 (and Vice-Versa) over Bluetooth.

I figured that I would open up a Server-Socket on the Windows Machine and program the Android app to start a Client-Socket. But being aware that Android SDP(Service Discovery Protocol) and connects By a UUID, created a point where in I am confused.

Confused on how I should start up a server socket on the Server Side Using the Windows API.
MY Question is whether android will detect the server socket if I merely start a Bluetooth socket with

```
SOCKET sock_s, sock_c;
SOCKADDR_BTH add1,add2;
sock_s =socket( AF_BTH,SOCK_STREAM,BTHPROTO_RFCOMM );
        if ( sock_s == INVALID_SOCKET )
            return -2;

        //Clearing the SOCKADDR_BTH variable
        memset(&add1,0,sizeof(add1));

        add1.addressFamily=AF_BTH;
        add1.serviceClassId=my_Guid;
```

Or is there another way to create a server socket that follows the SDP protocol on the MICROSOFT stack?

Comment: Guys any help would be good !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use native code on the Windows box?  If not use my library ([32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/)) its make such things easy e.g. [Bluetooth Server-side](http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bluetooth%20Server-side):

```vb
Class MyConsts
  Shared ReadOnly MyServiceUuid As Guid _
    = New Guid("{00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff}")
End Class

  ...
  Dim lsnr As New BluetoothListener(MyConsts.MyServiceUuid)
  lsnr.Start()
  ' Now accept new connections, perhaps using the thread pool to handle each
  Dim conn As New BluetoothClient = lsnr.AcceptBluetoothClient()
  Dim peerStream As Stream = conn.GetStream()
  ...
```

You could even 32feet.NET use it from C++ with C+++/CLR.

Or IIRC there is a simple way to get Windows [WSASetService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362921%28VS.85%29.aspx) to add a basic SDP record for your server socket (if you don't have a custom record to add).  Or get the RFCOMM port number from the Windows socket (getsockname) and tell the Android app to connect directly to that port number -- assuming it can do that...

Comment: thank you for your reply Alan, To be very honest with you. I have never used .NET before and am pretty speculative whether I can use your library. Looking at the above code you have presented I see that it would make my life very easy if I did go for it. I look forward to using that. On the other side, can you guide me on how I could setup the basic SDP record? that would point to the socket I have created? Cause most of my code is already written for NATIVE code.