# Android bluetooth remote control guidance for a project

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, client, controls

I'm in a dire need for some guidance on how to build an android bluetooth remote control.

I understand that two things would be needed. A server that will take request from the android device via bluetooth and the android device acting as a client.

I found this and i think it would help to a certain extent.
http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/

All i want is some guidance as to what i should start studying and how do i successfully build this thing in about two weeks. 
I'm not all that strong in Java. So you can provide me links and advices as to how i should start with it. Help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Additional details:
The remote control would be used for things like controlling vlc player, shutting down,restarting, controlling slides,etc.

Comment: what will this be a remote control to? What will your remote be controlling?

Comment: For performing remote actions like play,pause,restart,shutdown,etc

Comment: Do you have a specific device like a tv,computer,car or another android device to which you are targeting with your remote?

Comment: The device can be an android device and it will be controlling a windows based computer for now.

Comment: Sounds like a fun project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the lack of dedicated cohesive standards between [manufacturers Bluetooth device stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_stack), I'd recommend you start small and pick a specific device and action you wish to preform.

I'd start by attempting setup a Bluetooth server on a windows device and trying to get the server to receive a simple message (if that is the way you are going).

If you decide to go a different route and are thinking linux then take a look at [bluesZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_stack#BlueZ) which is the official  Linux Bluetooth protocol stack.

If you think of doing something a bit more towards the deep end of the pool then check out the [Ubertooth](http://ubertooth.sourceforge.net/) or the 
[Video Primer](http://hak5.org/episodes/hak5-920) and  [library for android usage](https://github.com/gnychis/ubertooth-android#readme)

[it's dangerous to go alone take this....](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/its-dangerous-to-go-alone-take-this) Set of resources to help you get started

- [msdn for dealing in raw socket programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362932(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [this SO Question lists some Windows api wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144862/bluetooth-apis-in-windows-net)
- [This shows an example bluetooth client and server in java](http://www.miniware.net/mobile/articles/viewarticle.php?id=22)
- [32feet has a simple way to roll your own simple bluetooth server](http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bluetooth%20Server-side)
- [This question seems to be along a similar vein to what you are wanting to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353939/bluetooth-android-to-windows-7)
- [Intro to BlueZ](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/)